# Cambiar nombre href de la URL

Tags: html, http, url, href

Hay alguna forma de poder cambiar en HTML o Jquery una URL, por ejemplo de:

http://ejemplo.com/index

a esto:

http://ejemplo.com/inicio

Teniendo en cuenta que el archivo se llama index.

Comment: Nos compartes que has intentado?

Comment: @BetaM Realmente no he probado nada, normalmente pongo index.html y about.html a los archivos, pero me gustaria que el nombre que sale en la URL fuera diferente, en este caso Inicio y Nosotros.

Comment: Trata algo y sobre eso podemos ayudarte

Comment: @BetaM He intentado sobreescribir en .htaccess con el tag RewriteRule pero no se exactamente como se hace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes remover las extensiones de archivos existentes (html en este caso) y hacer algunos mapeos usando creando un archivo .htaccess en la misma carpeta de tus archivos (en un servidor Apache o compatible con .htaccess)

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Asi, `/index.html` sera `/index`

Cambiar una pagina a otro nombre

```
RewriteRule ^inicio$ index.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: Justo es lo que tengo echo, el caso es que no se si hay alguna forma de cambiar ese "index" por un "inicio" en el mismo .htaccess.

Comment: Agregue instrucciones para eso. Saludos!

Comment: Tengo puesto:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L] 
Redirect /index.html /inicio

sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: Estas usando un servidor Apache para mostrar la pagina? Deberia funcionar a menos que el modulo Redirect no este activado. El otro cambio (quitar .html) funciona?

Comment: Tengo el Xampp tirando el apache sin problema. Si, las extensiones las ha quitado sin problema!

Comment: En ese caso hice un cambio con RewriteRule que parece funcionar para este caso. Redirect requiere que la redireccion sea un archivo existente.

Comment: PORFIN! Muchas gracias!